# How to generate an unique number from a given four numbers and getting these given numbers back from generated unique number?

Tags: java, memory, dictionary, key

I was using a Map(String,Integer) in java.
Keys were generated from string concatenation of four given numbers.

givenNumber1 at most 6 digits,
givenNumber2 at most 4 digits,
givenNumber3 at most 4 digits,
givenNumber4 at most 4 digits.

Because of memory cost, I want to use Map(Integer,Integer) in java.
Now how can I generate an unique number from given four numbers
and then how to get back these four numbers from this generated number?

Is there an efficient(memory,cpu) way to do it?

Comment: When you say at most 6 digits, do you mean exactly 6 digits? Is `0` valid?

Comment: yes 0 can be valid. First given number holds the permutation number it can start from 0 to at most 100000 permutations.  I thougt that fourth given number is stored in the last 4 digits. Second give number can hold in last 8,7,6 and 5. digits. This goes on, then I need Long.

Comment: I would use `TLongIntHashMap` if you want memory efficiency.

Comment: Thank you. I have heard Trove. I was wondering about any other way possible without using Long.

Comment: Guava has a primitives based collections.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.Max is 2,147,483,647(10 digits) and in your example you want to put 6 + 4 + 4 + 4 digits
so your max number is much bigger that max int 10 digits vs 18 digits.

So it's impossible to simply replace you map from Map < String, Integer > to Map < Integer, Integer>

Comment: Map<Long,Integer> can be used.